# My Tor Browser doesnt work anymore please HELP

Tags: proxy, mac

I am new in tor so if someone could explain me what to do to fix my problem I would appreciate it.

```
22/3/17 9:47:36 a. m..600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
22/3/17 9:47:36 a. m..600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 85.17.30.79:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:15937 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.147:13764 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.99.11.54:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.13:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.95.36.142:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.165:10527 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.9:443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
22/3/17 9:47:38 a. m..500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
22/3/17 9:47:43 a. m..400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
22/3/17 9:47:43 a. m..400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
22/3/17 9:47:43 a. m..400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: You're trying to use the default obfs4 bridges, they're probably blocked. Try `meek` or get fresh bridges from https://bridges.torproject.org